# Keep css positioning relative to window resizing

Tags: css, resize, window, element, positioning

Im working on some CSS with a web app that I am doing, and I have finally got what I want my page to look like encoded in the css.

```
#searchNavBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: -53%;
    top: -40px;
    height: 70px;
}

#searchResultsDoodle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

#searchResultsSearchBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 690px;
    height: 50px;
}

#searchResultsSearchButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 810px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

So I've got a navbar type thing along the top, with a picture, search bar, and a button. Actually taken heavy inspiration from google ;)

Things look good now, however, when I do a "ctrl+", increasing the size of the page, the formatting gets thrown completely off, the search bar drawn to the center of the page, etc... is there any way to write the CSS for this code such that, in the event I increase or decrease the size of the page, the things on the page will attempt to stay as close as they can, proportionally speaking, to the locations that I initially wanted them on the page?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML, please?

Comment: You're overusing positioning...there are much better options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for a jumping off point, I kind of just threw some stuff together until something worked.

Comment: Setting top/left with position:relative the source of all layout evils.

Comment: Cool, I had no idea.

Comment: @Diodeus, what do you mean by that? After reading the docs, I'm still not entirely sure. Should it be fixed?

Comment: Setting position in a relative element moves it around and really messes with what you think is going to happen with the child elements. If you really need to position the parent, use margins, not top/left.

Comment: cool, will do. My first attempt messing around with CSS as you can tell, couldnt really call myself a web developer without it :)